# How to integrate ckeditor gem with Rails 6 + Webpacker?

Tags: webpack, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-6

Throwing "Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined" error

```rb
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The ckeditor gem version 5 actually contains ckeditor-4, as of now.

There is also a ckeditor-5, which is based on webpack itself, and can be directly put into rails-6 webpack, without the need for a gem.

OTOH, while this is likely the more future-proof approach, ckeditor-5 differs in a number of things and may or may not suit your needs.